# Concatenate list of Objects arrays in Java8

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have list of 1D arrays wrapped in an object, I want to collect them in 1 single array using java-8 stream and collect.

Given class Item with an array of

```
class A{
 int x;
}


class Item{
    A[] parts=new A[];
    public A[] getParts(){
       return parts;
    }
}
```

So if I have list l

```
List<Item> l=new ArrayList<>();
l.add(new Item());
l.add(new Item());
```

I need to collect the content in these two object in one single array of type A.

So if first Item has `parts={1,2}` and 2nd Item `parts={3,4}` the output should be somehow like

```
A[] out={1,2,3,4}
```

I tried to do

```
l.stream().map(Item::getParts).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new A[n]);
```

but apperantly it has meany problems.

Comment: I deleted my answer, you will learn more by reading the Stream tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/. Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Your method is named `getParts()`, not `getparts()`. And Stream as a [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method, as well as a flatMap() method..

Comment: In order to stream the elements of an array, you must use `Arrays.stream(myArray)`. Currently, your list is a list of arrays, not a list of elements from the arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map each `Item` to its `A[]` array. Then when having a stream of `A[]` just flat map it to get each `A` of each array and make it one array at the end.

```
A[] array = l.stream().map(x -> x.getParts())
                      .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x))
                      .toArray(A[]::new); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

However, if you only interested in the `int` value, there is an extra step

```
int[] array = l.stream().map(x -> x.getParts())
                      .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x))
                      .mapToInt(x -> x.getX())
                      .toArray();
```

Comment: I recommend using `Arrays.stream` instead of `Stream.of` in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.flatMap()` instead of a `.map()`; in the lambda just generate a new stream of the items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
static void test() {
        List<Item> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(new Item(1, 2,5));
        l.add(new Item(3, 4,10));

        System.out.println(l);

        int totalNoOfParts = l.stream().mapToInt(item->item.getParts().length).reduce(0, Integer::sum);

        A[] allParts = l.stream().map(item -> item.getParts()).collect(() -> new A[totalNoOfParts],
                (c, e) -> System.arraycopy(e, 0, c, getNextPos(c), e.length),
                (c1, c2) -> System.arraycopy(c2, 0, c1, getNextPos(c1), c2.length));

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(allParts));

    }

    static int getNextPos(A[] a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == null)
                return i;
        }
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Invalid index value");
    }
```

I modified your Item class to have fixed length of array.

```
class Item {

    A[] parts = new A[3];

    Item(int... values) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(values, "Argument Not Valid");

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            parts[i] = new A();
            parts[i].x = values[i];
        }
    }

    public A[] getParts() {
        return parts;
    }
}
```